# SQL Find keys where one count is higher than another

Tags: sql, oracle

Okay so I have a table with contact historys. There could be two cases:

```
+----------+----------+
| "TEXTID" | "ACTION" |
+----------+----------+
| "1"      | "430"    |
| "1"      | "440"    |
| "1"      | "430"    |
| "2"      | "430"    |
+----------+----------+
```

Now I want to check this table for every textid, which has more 430 actions than 440 actions.

I tried with counts and subquerys, but for textid 2 the problem is that count of 440 doesnt return a value, so I cant compare 1 > 0.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

My code so far:

```
select textid
from tbltextkontakthist t
where t.aktion = 430
group by t.textid
having count(t.textkontakthistid) >
(select count(t2.textkontakthistid)
from tbltextkontakthist t2
where t2.aktion = 440
and t2.textid = t.textid
group by t2.textid);
```

Let me explain further: Action 430 marks a document as sighted, 440 removes that status. I want to see every document that is sighted (or the opposite). Since I have no other Yes/No mark in the database, I need to count for myself if the document was marked more often as sighted instead of marked as not sighted.

In other words, a document (textid) needs to have more actions '430' than '440'.

Comment: GROUP BY. HAVING with case expressions to do conditional counting.

Comment: Tried select textid from tbltextkontakthist t where t.aktion = 430 group by t.textid
having count(t.textkontakthistid) > (select case when count(t2.textkontakthistid) > 0  then count(t2.textkontakthistid) else 0 end as entsichtet from tbltextkontakthist t2 where t2.aktion = 440 and t2.textid = t.textid group by t2.textid); But this doesnt work, because, as I said, the count doesnt give me 0 as a result.

Comment: still not getting what you want ? plz add more details of expected output ?

Comment: `which has more 430 actions than 440 actions` Don't get what this means

Comment: Any expected result can display?

Comment: Please edit you question and add the attempt you've made to solve the problem.

Comment: See my edit....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT TEXTID
FROM <table>
GROUP BY TEXTID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Action=430 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE WHEN Action=440 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Assuming all you need is to compare 430s with 440s.